# SpringBoot server does not receive port when deployed in Istio

Tags: port, kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

I have a SpringBoot server deployed in Istio, running on :9091. Same port is open in Istio Ingress gateway, VirtualService is set up ...all good, I can reach the 9091 service from outside.
However, my app needs to read a URL with which the endpoint is being called and Looking at httpServletRequest.getRequestURL() shows no port. Meaning the request looks like it reached  port :80, although that can't be true, since the server is listening on :9091.

When I set up a port-forward for service at :9091, the port is correctly present in httpServletRequest

What is the issue here?
Why would Istio remove the port from request?

Edit: adding manifests

gateway-ports.yml:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istio-with-extra-ports
spec:
  profile: default
  meshConfig:
    enableTracing: true
    defaultConfig:
      tracing:
        sampling: 100
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - namespace: istio-system
        name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            ports:
              - port: 15021
                targetPort: 15021
                name: status-port
                protocol: TCP
              - port: 80
                targetPort: 8080
                name: http2
                protocol: TCP
              - port: 443
                targetPort: 8443
                name: https
                protocol: TCP
              - port: 15012
                targetPort: 15012
                name: tcp-istiod
                protocol: TCP
              - port: 15443
                targetPort: 15443
                name: tls
                protocol: TCP
              - port: 9091
                targetPort: 9091
                name: http-neo-dms-service
                protocol: TCP
```

gateway.yml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
    - port:
        number: 9091
        name: http-9091
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

deployment-and-service.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: neo-dms-service
  name: neo-dms-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: neo-dms-service
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neo-dms-service #tied to Service file spec.selector.app
      annotations:
        co.elastic.logs/enabled: "true"
        co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.keys_under_root: "true"
        co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.add_error_key: "true"
        co.elastic.logs.json-logging/json.message_key: "message"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: localhost:5000/my/image:1.0-SNAPSHOT
          name: neo-dms-service
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "50Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "500Mi"
              cpu: "2000m"
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 10"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: neo-dms-service
  name: neo-dms-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: 9091-9091
      port: 9091
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9091
  selector:
    app: neo-dms-service #tied Deployment file spec.template.metadata.labels.app
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: neo-dms-service-frontend
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: neo-dms-service.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 9091
```

I install Istio via `istioctl install -y -f gateway-ports.yml`
Then I label the default namespace with `kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled`

When the app is running I call its endpoint at port 9091 and check the request URL `httpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`. This URL now has port 80 - and that is what I would expect to be 9091.

Comment: Can you share some more details on your setup, like kubernetes manifests (Service, Deployment) and istio config (Gateway, VirtualSerive)

Comment: So you say all is working fine on 9091 but in your java app the application think that the request is from 80 port ?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque yes.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a couple of days attempting to troubleshoot the same issue. Spring application utilized the "x-forwarded-port" header to determine the client's request port before the gateway. However, Istio didn't do this by default.

This configuration enable x-forwarded-port appending to gateway Envoy sidecar.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: tweak-xforwarded-port
  namespace: istio-system # as defined in meshConfig resource.
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER # http connection manager is a filter in Envoy
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
            append_x_forwarded_port: true
```